# White-Blank page on Wordpress - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onePageNav is not a function

Tags: wordpress

I have encountered a problem today out of the blue. My site wont load on Chrome(It loads on safari, explorer). It only loads a blank white page and after 3-4 minutes it MAY open the content. The URL is: https://premonition.ai/newsite/wordpress.

Checking on the console I got this message (only when the screen is white)

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onePageNav is not a function
    at VM1047 general.js?ver=4.7.1:92
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM1047 general.js?ver=4.7.1:97)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.n.fn.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at VM1047 general.js?ver=4.7.1:38
```

When I click in one of the sub-errors I get this https://snag.gy/NhoP05.jpg.

I thought the error was from a plugin (Page scroll to id), but I didn't find the onePageNav function anywhere on the files of the plugin.

Can I somehow delete the whole function? Can I overwrite it?

Thank you,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have used One page Nav jquery. If you want to delete it, go to the js flie general.js and remove the onePageNav function. If you want to make it work then follow these points-

- Check whether you have included the [onePageNav jquery](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav/blob/master/jquery.nav.js), if not
  done, then please include it under your header file below the
  wp_head() function.
- Bind the onePageNav under this function-

  $( document ).ready(function() {
  //your function
          }

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help Rahul.

I check on header.php and onePageNav wasnt there. Should I copy paste the onePageNav jquery under the header below the wp_head() function?

What do you mean by bind?

Sorry, I kinda suck on js.

Thank you!

Comment: Create a file with .js extension and include the whole jquery https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav/blob/master/jquery.nav.js
under your file, place it in js folder of your theme and include this code in header.php-
<script type="text/javascript" src="enter path of the js file here"></script>

Comment: Thank you!
Instead of trying to fix that, I remove the onePagenav from general.js. But another function scrollUp is doing the same thing... I think I will have to continue removing those functions, until hopefully it loads smoothly. Your thoughts?

Tom

Comment: If those jquery are not of use then it's better to remove them